# 403 access denied error for files uploaded to s3 using aws command line tool

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload images to s3 using the aws command line tool. I keep getting a 403 access denied error.

I think the --acl flag from here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html should fix this but all the options I've tried haven't helped.

I have a django app running which uploads to s3 and I can access those images fine.

Answer (score 1):

did you set any IAM or bucket policy to allow upload to your bucket?
There is (at least) 3 ways to enable a user to access a bucket:

- specify an acl at the bucket level (go to the bucket page, select your bucket and click "properties", there you can grant more accesses)
- attach a policy to the bucket itself, e.g to something like:

  > {
  >     "Version": "2012-10-17",
  >     "Statement": [
  >         {
  >             "Sid": "Example permissions",
  >             "Effect": "Allow",
  >             "Principal": {
  >                 "AWS": "arn of user or role"
  >             },
  >             "Action": [
  >                 "s3:ListBucket",
  >                 "s3:GetBucketLocation",
  >                 "s3:PutObject"
  >             ],
  >             "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your bucket name"
  >         }
  >     ]
  >   }
- attach an policy to your IAM user, e.g to give admin rights:go to IAM > users > your user > attach policy > AmazonS3FullAccess

If you want to build your own policy, you can use the aws [policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)

If you want more specific help, please provide more details (which users should have which permissions on your bucket, etc)

hope this helps