# S3: The bucket can not be accessed by its root account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The permission granting things of S3 is rather complicated. As far as I have understood the root account (that with email login) should have access to anything, except for objects in bucket which do not belong to it (which is not the case).

My setting:

```
> a root account, called: myroot a IAM user, called myiam, whose parent
> account is myroot
```

myiam create a bucket, called mybucket. without granting permission, myroot can not have access to it.

I looked up the aws documentation(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html), think that shouldn't be the case

By default, all Amazon S3 resources are private. Only a resource owner can access the resource. The resource owner refers to the AWS account that creates the resource. For example:

> The AWS account that you use to create buckets and objects owns those
>   resources. If you create an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)
>   user in your AWS account, your AWS account is the parent owner. If the
>   IAM user uploads an object, the parent account, to which the user
>   belongs, owns the object.

Comment: what error do you get? 403 denied?

Comment: @Tom not sure. I used console. It says "Sorry! You do not have permissions to view this bucket"

Comment: see if you have the correct rights on the bucket itself, maybe you have sth like an S3 bucket with an explicit "deny" on it. See my answer to the following link where I described the access the S3 buckets, maybe this is sth to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730317/403-access-denied-error-for-files-uploaded-to-s3-using-aws-command-line-tool/31790746#31790746

Comment: @Tom thanks for the response. but the root account could have access to any bucket under its account, shouldn't it ?

Comment: if you created the user in the console, no. IAM users by default have no permissions on them. You have to add permissions from the base AWS account.

Comment: If you have set a bucket policy on your S3 bucket with an explicit deny, then even the root can't describe the bucket. e.g:    "Effect": "Deny",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work just fine.

I did the following to test your situation:

- Logged in as an IAM user (using account, username, password)
- Created a bucket in the console
- Uploaded an object (which stays private by default)
- Logged in a root account (using email address, password, MFA)
- I was able to view the contents of the bucket in the console
- I was able to view the contents of the uploaded object (using `Actions -> Open` to generate a Signed URL)

Comment: that is true, because after having created a bucket the default grantee is set to root account, also the owner is root account. But if you delete this default grantee, then only the creator of the bucket (your IAM user in this case) can have access to it, not even the owner which is the root account. That is the point confusing me

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. Yes... while removing the "grantee" option will stop the root account from having access, the root account can add the access rights back again and can therefore access the bucket. There is no way to stop the root account from adding their own access permissions.